# Flickering rendering

Tags: rendering

Please see this video
https://youtu.be/8oBZGZTsP9g

I am getting flickering in the bottle, is there a rendering setting to suppress this?

I had this problem on another project before, but I didn't know how to solve it and ended up rendering it.
But it still looks ugly and I would like to solve it.

Comment: It's probably some denoising problem. Try to adjust its parameters.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. And Thank you! I will try it!